# CIFS mount is returning errors when operating on remote files (file exists, interrupted system call)

Tags: sed, rsync, mv, cifs, system-calls

I need to replace a string in a file located in a CIFS mount (NTFS NAS). It is mounted with

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,guest,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.1/hdd /hdd
```

I never faced this problem until a week ago, but I didn't change any mount option

---

If I run `sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/' /hdd/file` I get

```
sed: preserving permissions for ‘/hdd/sedgtQccm’: Not a directory
sed: cannot rename /hdd/sedgtQccm: File exists
```

If I run `sed 's/oldstring/newstring/' /hdd/file > /hdd/file.tmp && mv /hdd/file.tmp /hdd/file` I get

```
mv: cannot move '/hdd/file.tmp' to '/hdd/file': File exists
```

If I run  `sed 's/oldstring/newstring/' /hdd/file > /hdd/file.tmp && rsync /hdd/file.tmp /hdd/file` I get

```
rsync: [receiver] rename "/hdd/file.tmp.GMn4i1" -> "file": File exists (17)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1287) [sender=3.2.2]
```

I get these errors if

- both files are remote
- file is remote and file.tmp is local

I don't get them if

- both files are local
- file is local and file.tmp is remote

---

It's also worth mentioning that if I download a large file I get

```
write /hdd/largefilefromweb: interrupted system call
```

And that if I play my music from there almost hourly I get

```
Encountered error while transfering /hdd/track.mp3: Read error: Interrupted system call
```

EDIT: A workaround to the `sed`, `mv` and `rsync` problem is `rm`ing the file before performing the second command:

```bsh
sed 's/oldstring/newstring/' /hdd/file > /hdd/file.tmp && rm /hdd/file && mv /hdd/file.tmp /hdd/file
# instead of
sed 's/oldstring/newstring/' /hdd/file > /hdd/file.tmp && mv /hdd/file.tmp /hdd/file
```

Answer (score 2):

In regards to the "File exists" issue, as mentioned in [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/a/1025993/583813), I believe this is a regression in recent kernels and downgrading to `5.7.7` avoids the issue for now.

Comment: I see you mention `5.4.50` as safe fallback, this machine is running on `5.4.51` at the moment, so yes, it could be. I confirm that the problem appears on another machine running `5.7.9`; has this issue been reported to upstream?

Comment: Yes, the issue is [reported](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2020-July/135581.html)